# Qt Installer framework, uninstalling / updating offline

Tags: qt, frameworks, installation, cross-platform

I'm trying to make an installer using the Qt Installer framework and when an upgrade is available in the software (checked through our rest API), our software will download the new installer and run it.

This should of course uninstall the previous version first, however, it seems just running it will give you "The folder you selected already exists..." error.

I thought using the maintenance tool that is generated would provide a solution, however, it seems that there is no way to run this with a switch to just do the uninstall. It shows up with the dialogue of uninstall, upgrade... which would confuse the users.

Is there a way to get the maintenance tool or otherwise to uninstall the program, so the update can be run?

EDIT:
If this cannot be done, can anyone suggest a good cross platform installer framework?

Comment: Exactly the same situation here. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to run the installer again, run the maintenancetool.exe to update. You can make a "silent" update by passing a script to the maintenance tool like this:

```
@echo off
maintenancetool.exe --checkupdates > checkUpdate.txt

findstr /c:"updates" checkUpdate.txt

if %errorlevel% == 0 maintenancetool.exe --script=script.qs
```

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html